# Перевести код Паскаль в Пайтон

Tags: python, pascal

пытался самостоятельно, но увы ничего не получилось. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее спасибо.
Вот Паскаль код:

```pascal
a:= 1;
For i := 2 to n do begin
  j := i; k := 0; l := 0;
  While j mod 2 = 0 do begin
    j := j div 2;  
    k := k+1; 
  end; 
  a:= (a*j) mod 10;
  While j mod 5 = 0 do begin 
    j := j div 5;  
    l :=l+1      
  end;
  a:= (a*j) mod 10;
  k := k-l;             
  For i := k downto 1 do 
    a:= (a*2) mod 10 
  end;  
end
```

Вот то что у меня получилось:

```py
a=1
for i in range(2,n+1):
    j=i
    k=0
    l=0
    while j%2==0:
        j=j // 2;
        k+=1;
        a=(a*j)%10
    while j%5==0:
        j=j//5
        l+=1
        a=(a*j)%10
        k=k-l
        for i in range(k,0,-1):
            a=(a*2)%10
```

Comment: следите за отступами.

Comment: обратный цикл `for i in range(k,0,-1):` С отступами беда, да.

Comment: окей, буду исправлять. А так в целом остальное все правильно?

Comment: while циклы в паскале быстро заканчиваются, а в питоне нет

Comment: @MBo я паскаль толком не знаю. Можете более понятно объяснить что мне нужно исправить в циклах while?

Comment: ну вы же понимаете, что end завершает цикл в pascal?

Comment: @MBo конечно понимаю

Comment: @MBo  то есть мне   нужно break использовать чтобы завершить цикл?

Comment: А в питоне конец цикла обозначается возвратом на тот же уровень отступа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
a = 1
for i in range(2, n + 1):
    j = 1
    k = 0
    l = 0
    while j % 2 == 0:
        j = j // 2
        k += 1
    a = (a * j) % 10
    while j % 5 == 0:
        j = j // 5
        l += 1
    a = (a * j) % 10
    k = k - l
    for i in range(k, 0, -1):
        a = (a * 2) % 10
```